# What are the recommended specifications of Virtual Machines (Hyper-V) to run Sharepoint 2010 for around 400 people?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, virtualization, hyper-v

I have been tasked to set up SharePoint 2010 on a Virtual Machine (Hyper V), and I have loads of resources at my disposal. I want to know what will the best practiced (or optimal) hardware and software specifications be to set up SharePoint 2010 on this Virtual Machine, it needs to at least support up to 400 people. I found some guides on the Microsoft website at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx . As far as I know, Microsoft sees Small Deployments as machines that are able to support 2500 people, which is way too much for me.

Can anyone please help?

**EDIT**

```
Server 1 – Web Frontend Server
•   Windows 2008 R2 64-bit
•   CPU: ?
•   RAM: ?
•   HDD Space: ?
•   External IP? Yes/No
•   Ports open: 80, 443, ???
Server 2 – Application Server
•   Windows 2008 R2 64-bit
•   CPU: ?
•   RAM: ?
•   HDD Space: 
•   External IP: Yes/No
•   Ports Open: 80,443, ???

SQL Server 
•   Standard/Enterprise edition?
•   New Instance?
•   Service account for instance?
•   Full-text search?
•   Maintenance plans?
•   Space requirements?
Sharepoint Setup
•   Domain name: ???.XXXXXXXXX.XXX
•   Email Server to use: ???
•   Service Accounts: XXXXX\???
```

** ANOTHER EDIT **

I already have some of the data, like SQL Data. Ignore SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Planning guide for server farms and environments for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21097 will give your more precise answers than I'll ever will but anyway :

For 400 users, depending on the actions that your users will do and the number / load of synchroneous operations, you could even go for a standalone farm (everything on a single server). If you have a separate SQL Server 2008 Server, that will be even better as all database operations will be handled by this additional server.

You'll want a 64 bits Windows 2008 R2 / SQL Server 2008, at least 8gb of ram (the more you can give, the better).

Microsoft recommand at least a four cores CPU but you can go with only 2 (but you don't seem to have issue with ressources) For your WFE / App server I would allocate 80 ~ 120gb of disk, for the SQL Server, it will depend on the content / database recovery model / versioning you'll have (and many other factors like the search database size if you plan on having search functionnalities).

At the end, it's all about the usage of your farm. You can have 400 users on which 80% will read data while only 20% will contribute or you can have 10 users that will inject gbs of data each day... It's hard to advice you without knowing the business requirements that you need to fullfill.

Also Checkout the capacity planning from MS : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758645.aspx, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758647.aspx as well as for SQL Server with SharePoint in mind : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801%28office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Perfect! thanks, got all I needed to know from these pages you linked. I did see some of them, but scoffed since the requirements seemed huge. thanks for the confidence boost